# Deleting a Wordpress user using a custom plugin Hook

Tags: wordpress, hook

I am new to wordpress hooks and I am trying to delete a wordpress user using a custom action the plugin Restrict Content Pro provides.
(https://docs.restrictcontentpro.com/article/2054-group-accounts-actions-filters)
What I want to achieve: When a member is removed from a group, their account should be deleted.
Unfortunately my code doesn't work. Any ideas on how to modify it be highly appreciated!

```
function delete_group_user() {
wp_delete_user($user_id->ID );
}
add_action( 'rcpga_remove_member', 'delete_group_user' );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are close, your function `delete_group_user()` does not have `$user_id` defined. Luckily, it looks like the [`rcpga_remove_member`](https://docs.restrictcontentpro.com/article/2054-group-accounts-actions-filters) hook provides that information. Something like this should work:

```
function delete_group_user($user_id) {
    wp_delete_user($user_id);
}
add_action( 'rcpga_remove_member', 'delete_group_user' );
```

Also, note from the documentation that `$user_id` is an INT not an object.